# What is uavParam and uavParam.ic in "Waypoint Follower for Fixed-Wing UAV" example (UAV toolbox)?

Tags: matlab, simulink, toolbox

I discovered uavParam variable which has several fields (at least two: uavParam.ic.Pos_0 - for initial position probably and uavParam.ic.gsLL).
It is located inside Waypoints constant vector - the input of UAV Waypoint Follower block [in this mathworks example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/uav/ug/tuning-waypoint-follower-for-fixed-wing.html) (pathFollowing.slx; 5x3 by default; left side of a screenshot inside).
I understand that this vector is for our desired points in the path. But what is this "uavParam" for and where can i find any documentation about this? At least which fields does this uavParam have?

Didn't find anything even inside simulink example (also tried ctrl+f and typed uavParam).